# Remove CRLF midway through field from data read in as .CSV data file, replace with "||"

Tags: python, r

I'm reading lines of comma-separated data in windows OS, with python 3.8.2.

Some fields have embedded CRLF midway through, as in this particular record, which has multiline data, such as:

"John SmithCRLFJaneDoe"

Data in source was entered as:

```
"John Smith
Jane Doe"
```

When I read this line and want to convert it into a string, I get str = "John Smith", as the read parser chops off at CRLF.

So I'm trying to replace the midway CRLF with some other character:

```
with open('bogus_line.csv', 'r') as MyLine:
    str = MyLine.read()
    print (str)  
    raw_string = str.replace('\\r\\n'," || ")
    print (raw_string)   # the problem is is generating the correct raw string format???
```

Produces:

```
"John Smith
Jane Doe"
"John Smith
Jane Doe"
```

But I would like:

```
"John Smith
Jane Doe"
"John Smith || Jane Doe"
```

Below doesn't work, returning an error:

```
with open('bogus_line.csv', 'r') as MyLine:
    str = MyLine.read()
    print (str)  
    raw_string = r'str.replace('\\r\\n'," || ")
    print (raw_string)
```

You would expect below to work, but it chugs through as in the first example, completing, but not merging the two lines:

```
with open('bogus_line.csv', 'r') as MyLine:
    str = MyLine.read()
    print (str)  
    raw_string = r"{}".format(str).replace('\\r\\n'," || ")
    print (raw_string)
```

Produces:

```
"John Smith
Jane Doe"
"John Smith
Jane Doe"
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is to use the csv module that knows about newlines embedded in quoted fields:

```
import csv

with open('bogus_line.csv', 'r') as MyLine:
    rd = csv.reader(MyLine)
    str = next(rd)[0]    # a reader is an iterator on lists of fields
    print (str)  
    raw_string = r"{}".format(str).replace('\\r\\n'," || ")
    print (raw_string)
```

Comment: hi, thx for reply and example. That is very similar to what I’m doing in the bigger code. When I run your example through the bogus_line.csv, I still produce both lines, with CRLF:
John Smith
Jane Doe
John Smith
Jane Doe
I think there might be something wrong with my search?? Not sure if its finding the windows version of CRLF?? When I view bogus_line in notepad with all characters, it shows CRLF though separating the two people.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to make this work, but its a bit tricky. you have to remove the \n and then the \r separately! don't ask me why or how. but this appears to work on a windows 10 platform: first remove newline, replacing with a space; next remove the carriage return.

```
raw_string = str.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```